# Insert row using a SELECT, and update the source table row with the target new row Id

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table SourceTable and I want to copy some of its data into TargetTable. TargetTable is an existing table with existing rows, and an identity id.

On SourceTable, there is a column that is a foreign key to TargetTable, e.g. SouceTable.TargetTableId

What I need to do is insert the rows from SourceTable into TargetTable, and then update the SourceTable.TargetTableId with the newly created Id from TargetTable.

I cannot do an insert and then a subsequent update by matching on multiple columns as the rows are not unique enough.

The insert needs to "insert into new table and update existing table's column that is a foreign key to the new table with the new row's id".

```sql
CREATE TABLE #SourceTable
(
    Id INT IDENTITY(1,1),
    Field1 NVARCHAR(MAX),
    Field2 NVARCHAR(MAX),
    TargetTableId INT
)

CREATE TABLE #TargetTable
(
    Id INT IDENTITY(245,1),
    Field1 NVARCHAR(MAX),
    Field2 NVARCHAR(MAX),
)

INSERT INTO #SourceTable(Field1, Field2)
VALUES
('Apple','Pie'),
('Chocolate','Cake'),
('Apple','Pie')

INSERT INTO #TargetTable(Field1, Field2)
SELECT Field1, Field2
FROM #SourceTable
```

Desired Result on SourceTable:

```
Id - Field1 - Field2 - TargetTableId
1 - Apple - Pie - 245
2 - Chocolate - Cake - 246
3 - Apple - Pie - 247
```

Comment: `INSERT` and ` OUTPUT` into an another table, and then you have the new IDs? The above is really vague. Sample data, expected results **and** *your attempts* will help us help you.

Comment: It sounds like you should probably consider using an AFTER INSERT trigger that then adds the `@@IDENTITY` into the SourceTable.

Comment: Considering the OP says "rows" @SchmitzIT , I suspect `@@IDENTITY` (or better `SCOPE_IDENTITY`) is going to provide the values the OP wants.

Comment: @Larnu. Post updated with sample data and expected results. Many thanks.

Comment: Wjere are 245, 246, and 247 coming from?

Comment: 245 246 247 are the new rows created on TargetTable (in the example I made TargetTable Identity start at 245)

Comment: @Larnu - I saw the part about rows not being unique enough as the reason for using a trigger instead. It'd just about be the only way to get the inserted identity value. You're right in the `SCOPE_IDENTITY` being better., though :)

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you need to use the old `MERGE` method to `OUTPUT` values from both the source data and the destination. Then you can put that data into a table variable/temporary table and use that to perform your `UPDATE`:

```sql
MERGE #TargetTable TT
USING #SourceTable ST ON ST.TargetTableId = TT.ID
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
    INSERT (Field1,Field2)
    VALUES(ST.Field1, ST.Field2)
OUTPUT ST.ID, inserted.ID INTO @IDs;

UPDATE ST
SET TargetTableId = I.TargetID
FROM #SourceTable ST
     JOIN @IDs I ON ST.Id = I.SourceID;
GO

SELECT *
FROM #SourceTable;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this as you needed.

- just create temp table #**TargetTableForInsert**
- insert this data too into this table with added ID of SourceTable
- and finally update your main table based on *TargetTableForInsert*

Here you are :)

```
CREATE TABLE #SourceTable
(
    Id INT IDENTITY(1,1),
    Field1 NVARCHAR(MAX),
    Field2 NVARCHAR(MAX),
    TargetTableId INT
)

CREATE TABLE #TargetTable
(
    Id INT IDENTITY(245,1),
    Field1 NVARCHAR(MAX),
    Field2 NVARCHAR(MAX)
)


CREATE TABLE #TargetTableForInsert
(
    Id INT IDENTITY(245,1),
    Field1 NVARCHAR(MAX),
    Field2 NVARCHAR(MAX),
    SourceTableId INT
)


INSERT INTO #SourceTable(Field1, Field2)
VALUES
('Apple','Pie'),
('Chocolate','Cake'),
('Apple','Pie')

INSERT INTO #TargetTable(Field1, Field2)
SELECT Field1, Field2 
FROM #SourceTable

INSERT INTO #TargetTableForInsert(Field1, Field2, SourceTableId)
SELECT Field1, Field2 ,Id
FROM #SourceTable


update #SourceTable
set TargetTableId =  ST.Id
FROM #SourceTable ST
     join #TargetTableForInsert TG on ST.id = TG.SourceTableId





select 'SourceTable',* from #SourceTable

select 'SourceTable',* from #TargetTable
```

Comment: Thanks Adamszsz. Agree this would work for my example in my original post. Many thanks, However, in the real thing I am trying to do I am not using newly created temp table - they are existing tables, and i dont want to add a new column to "TargetTable.

Comment: Edited , check now as you wanted :)